# Preloading images in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, beginner, image

I'm working on a little game where you press a button and a new image appears. There's a glitch every time you ask a new image to display and it occurred to me that I should preload the necessary images. However, I'm not sure how to do this efficiently as I'm not using a variable to display the images. It's also been pointed out to me that I should look into storing reference for the elements, but I don't know how to go about doing so. [This](http://theyellowparachute.com/test/Jajo/) is what I'm working on. Any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<body onLoad="setup()">
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="jajo"></div><!--this is where jajo will be displayed-->
        <div id="directions"></div><!--directions for how to interact with jajo-->
    </div><!--wrapper-->
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Calls the loadJajo function and passes the image URL
// Initiates directionSlide function
function setup() {
loadJajo('jajo.png');
elem = document.getElementById('directions');
directionSlide();
}

//Creates a new image object (Jajo) and writes it to the page.
function loadJajo(jajoSRC) {
var main = document.getElementById('jajo'); // Creates an variable to represent the "main" division
var defaultJajo = document.createElement('img'); // Creates a new image object (default Jajo image)
defaultJajo.src = jajoSRC; // adds the source file name to the defaultJajo image object
main.appendChild(defaultJajo); //puts the defaultJajo object inside the "main" division
}

// Listen for key pressed events.
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
var keyPress = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode); // Assigns value of key pressed to variable.

if(keyPress == "W") { // If 'W' is pressed, display Jajo waving.
    document.getElementById("jajo").innerHTML= "<img alt='car' src='jajo_wave.png'>";
    document.onkeyup = function(event) { // If 'W' is released, display default Jajo.
        document.getElementById("jajo").innerHTML= "<img alt='Jajo' src='jajo.png'>";
    }
} else if(keyPress == "A") { // If 'A' is pressed, display Jajo winking.
    document.getElementById("jajo").innerHTML= "<img alt='car' src='jajo_wink.png'>";
    document.onkeyup = function(event) { // If 'A' is released, display default Jajo.
        document.getElementById("jajo").innerHTML= "<img alt='Jajo' src='jajo.png'>";
    }
} else if(keyPress == "S") { // If 'S' is pressed, display transparent Jajo.
    document.getElementById("jajo").innerHTML= "<img alt='car' src='jajo_invisible.png'>";
    document.onkeyup = function(event) { // If 'S' is released, display default Jajo.
        document.getElementById("jajo").innerHTML= "<img alt='Jajo' src='jajo.png'>";
    }
} else if(keyPress == "D") { // If 'D' is pressed, display purple Jajo.
    document.getElementById("jajo").innerHTML= "<img alt='car' src='jajo_purple.png'>";
    document.onkeyup = function(event) { // If 'D' is released, display default Jajo.
        document.getElementById("jajo").innerHTML= "<img alt='Jajo' src='jajo.png'>";
    }
} else if(keyPress == "E") { // If 'E' is pressed, display Jajo eating a carrot.
    document.getElementById("jajo").innerHTML= "<img alt='car' src='jajo_carrot.png'>";
    document.onkeyup = function(event) { // If 'E' is released, display default Jajo.
        document.getElementById("jajo").innerHTML= "<img alt='Jajo' src='jajo.png'>";
    }
}
}

var elem;
var i = 0; // Counter variable.
// Array with directions for interacting with Jajo.
var directionArray = ["This is Jajo, your new pet monster!",
             "Jajo wants to say 'Hi!'<br>Press and hold 'W'",
             "Jajo has some special skills.<br>Press and hold 'D' to see one!",
             "Jajo is hungry for a healthy snack.<br>Press and hold 'E'",
             "Jajo wants to show you his secret power.<br>Press and hold 'S'",
             "That secret is just between you and Jajo!<br>Press and hold 'A'"];

// Transitions one direction to the next.
function nextDirection() {
i++; // Continuously add 1 to i.
elem.style.opacity = 0; // Directions opacity at 0%.
if(i > (directionArray.length - 1)) { // Resets counter to 0 when it reaches the end of the array.
    i = 0;
}
setTimeout(directionSlide,1000); // Set time delay for transition between directions.
}

// Displays direction one at a time.
// http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1380
function directionSlide() {
elem.innerHTML = directionArray[i]; // Displays direction based on position of counter variable.
elem.style.opacity = 1; // Direction opacity at 100%.
setTimeout(nextDirection,5000); // Set time delay for display of directions.
}
```

Comment: Do all the images need to be individual? you'd most likely be better of using a sprite sheet loading that.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050152/why-use-a-sprite-sheet-rather-than-individual-images

Answer (score 3):

From a once over:

- Please indent your functions, bad:

  ```
  function setup() {
  loadJajo('jajo.png');
  elem = document.getElementById('directions');
  directionSlide();
  }
  ```

  better:

  ```
  function setup() {
      loadJajo('jajo.png');
      elem = document.getElementById('directions');
      directionSlide();
  }
  ```
- Consider having only 1 comma separated `var` statement on the top of your code
- Lighten up on the comments, you are overdoing it, this:

  ```
  //Creates a new image object (Jajo) and writes it to the page.
  function loadJajo(jajoSRC) {
  var main = document.getElementById('jajo'); // Creates an variable to represent the "main" division
  var defaultJajo = document.createElement('img'); // Creates a new image object (default Jajo image)
  defaultJajo.src = jajoSRC; // adds the source file name to the defaultJajo image object
  main.appendChild(defaultJajo); //puts the defaultJajo object inside the "main" division
  }
  ```

  could be this:

  ```
  //Creates a new image object (Jajo) and writes it to the page.
  function loadJajo(jajoSRC) {
    var main = document.getElementById('jajo'), 
        defaultJajo = document.createElement('img'); 
    defaultJajo.src = jajoSRC; 
    main.appendChild(defaultJajo); 
  }
  ```
- You are actually storing a reference to an element here:

  ```
  elem = document.getElementById('directions');
  ```

  However, you should call `elem` differently, probably `directions`. Also, you should consider caching `document.getElementById('jajo')` since you use it a ton of times.
- There is a clear mapping in your code between key presses and images, you could write your `keydown` handler like this:

  ```
  var keyImageMap = 
  {
    'W' : 'jajo_wave.png',      // If 'W' is released, display default Jajo.
    'A' : 'jajo_wink.png',      // If 'A' is pressed, display Jajo winking.
    'S' : 'jajo_invisible.png', // If 'S' is pressed, display transparent Jajo.
    'D' : 'jajo_purple.png',    // If 'D' is pressed, display purple Jajo.
    'E' : 'jajo_carrot.png'     // If 'E' is pressed, display Jajo eating a carrot.
  }

  // Listen for key pressed events.
  document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    // Assigns value of key pressed to variable.
    var keyPress = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode); 

    if( keyImageMap[ keyPress ] )
    {
      document.getElementById('jajo').innerHTML = '<img alt="car" src="' + keyImageMap[ keyPress ] + '">';
    }
  }
  ```
- In the previous sample code you should of course have used a reference to `jajo` instead of calling `document.getElementById`. Also you should have deep thoughts on rewriting that image tag every time, perhaps it would be better to have a reference to the image and then keep changing `src`